# String comparison in Makeppfile

Tags: makefile, makepp

As part of my project, I work with c++ tests and I have to pass an argument to only a particular test based. So what I've done is in my **Makeppfile**,

```
ifeq($(TESTNAME), "t_wfi" )
  genArg1 += -force_wfi
endif
```

But now, there are more tests added that have t_wfi in the begining of its name. I want all those also to be passed the same args. Will this code help in that? If not, Can someone help me do it???

Answer (score 0):

```
ifneq (,$(filter t_wfi%,$(TESTNAME)))
  genArg1 += -force_wfi
endif
```